# Android ImageView, OnTouchEvent not moving it

Tags: android, imageview, ontouchlistener

I'm trying to make a simple app, with an imageview that can be zoomed in and out with buttons, and when zoomed, user could move around it with his fingers.

I've been reading the whole day, here and there, found different solutions. But I can't seem to make my picture move. Thing is, I want to keep the program like it is now, but just maybe change the `imageview OnTouchEvent`.

I'm adding my code:

```
public class LoadMap extends Activity {
ZoomControls zoom;
ImageView img;
ImageButton linkButton;
float startX, startY;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_load_map);

        zoom = (ZoomControls) findViewById(R.id.zoomControls1);
        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        linkButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.infopoint);

        startX = img.getScaleX();
        startY = img.getScaleY();

        img.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) img.getLayoutParams();

                        int x = (int) event.getRawX();
                        int y = (int) event.getRawY();

                        mParams.leftMargin = x;
                        mParams.topMargin = y;

                        img.setLayoutParams(mParams);                           
                    }
                return false;
            }
        });

        linkButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Uri uri = Uri.parse("just some site");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                startActivity(intent);                  
            }
        });

        zoom.setOnZoomInClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                float x = img.getScaleX();
                float y = img.getScaleY();

                img.setScaleX((float) (x+1));
                img.setScaleY((float) (y+1));                   
            }
        });

        zoom.setOnZoomOutClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                float x = img.getScaleX();
                float y = img.getScaleY();
                if((x>startX) & (y>startY)) {
                    img.setScaleX((float) (x-1));
                    img.setScaleY((float) (y-1));
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Is there a way to just change some things inside this method without messing my app too much and is this even possible the way I'm trying to make it work or my program logic is wrong.

```
img.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {          
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) img.getLayoutParams();

                        int x = (int) event.getRawX();
                        int y = (int) event.getRawY();

                        mParams.leftMargin = x;
                        mParams.topMargin = y;

                        img.setLayoutParams(mParams);                           
                    }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Sorry, if it has been asked before, but i searched alot and couldn't find anything specific for my 'problem'.
Thanks alot to whoever spends some time on my problem :).

Answer (score 1):

try this code,

put this code on image setOnTouchListener,

```
img.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                 @Override
                 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                       LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams) img
                                     .getLayoutParams();
                       switch (event.getAction()) {
                       case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                              break;
                       case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                              int x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
                              int y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();

                              if (x_cord > windowwidth) {
                                     x_cord = windowwidth;
                              }
                              if (y_cord > windowheight) {
                                     y_cord = windowheight;
                              }

                              layoutParams.leftMargin = x_cord - 25;
                              layoutParams.topMargin = y_cord - 75;

                              img.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                              break;
                       default:
                              break;
                       }
                       return true;
                 }
          });
```

I hope it will solve your problem..

Answer (score 0):

Try using a custom ImageVIew

```
public class ZoomableImageView extends ImageView implements OnTouchListener {
    private Context mContext;
    final private float MAX_SCALE = 2f;

    private Matrix mMatrix;
    private final float[] mMatrixValues = new float[9];

    // display width height.
    private int mWidth;
    private int mHeight;

    private int mIntrinsicWidth;
    private int mIntrinsicHeight;

    private float mScale;
    private float mMinScale;

    private float mPrevDistance;
    private boolean isScaling;

    private int mPrevMoveX;
    private int mPrevMoveY;
    private GestureDetector mDetector;

    final String TAG = "ScaleImageView";

    public ZoomableImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context, attr);
        this.mContext = context;
        initialize();
    }

    public ZoomableImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.mContext = context;
        initialize();
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
        super.setImageBitmap(bm);
        this.initialize();
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageResource(int resId) {
        super.setImageResource(resId);
        this.initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        this.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
        this.mMatrix = new Matrix();
        Drawable d = getDrawable();
        if (d != null) {
            mIntrinsicWidth = d.getIntrinsicWidth();
            mIntrinsicHeight = d.getIntrinsicHeight();
            setOnTouchListener(this);
        }
        mDetector = new GestureDetector(mContext,
                new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
                        maxZoomTo((int) e.getX(), (int) e.getY());
                        cutting();
                        return super.onDoubleTap(e);
                    }
                });

    }

    @Override
    protected boolean setFrame(int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        mWidth = r - l;
        mHeight = b - t;

        mMatrix.reset();
        int rNorm = r - l;
        mScale = (float) rNorm / (float) mIntrinsicWidth;

        int paddingHeight = 0;
        int paddingWidth = 0;
        // scaling vertical
        if (mScale * mIntrinsicHeight > mHeight) {
            mScale = (float) mHeight / (float) mIntrinsicHeight;
            mMatrix.postScale(mScale, mScale);
            paddingWidth = (r - mWidth) / 2;
            paddingHeight = 0;
            // scaling horizontal
        } else {
            mMatrix.postScale(mScale, mScale);
            paddingHeight = (b - mHeight) / 2;
            paddingWidth = 0;
        }
        mMatrix.postTranslate(paddingWidth, paddingHeight);

        setImageMatrix(mMatrix);
        mMinScale = mScale;
        zoomTo(mScale, mWidth / 2, mHeight / 2);
        cutting();
        return super.setFrame(l, t, r, b);
    }

    protected float getValue(Matrix matrix, int whichValue) {
        matrix.getValues(mMatrixValues);
        return mMatrixValues[whichValue];
    }

    protected float getScale() {
        return getValue(mMatrix, Matrix.MSCALE_X);
    }

    public float getTranslateX() {
        return getValue(mMatrix, Matrix.MTRANS_X);
    }

    protected float getTranslateY() {
        return getValue(mMatrix, Matrix.MTRANS_Y);
    }

    protected void maxZoomTo(int x, int y) {
        if (mMinScale != getScale() && (getScale() - mMinScale) > 0.1f) {
            // threshold 0.1f
            float scale = mMinScale / getScale();
            zoomTo(scale, x, y);
        } else {
            float scale = MAX_SCALE / getScale();
            zoomTo(scale, x, y);
        }
    }

    public void zoomTo(float scale, int x, int y) {
        if (getScale() * scale < mMinScale) {
            return;
        }
        if (scale >= 1 && getScale() * scale > MAX_SCALE) {
            return;
        }
        mMatrix.postScale(scale, scale);
        // move to center
        mMatrix.postTranslate(-(mWidth * scale - mWidth) / 2,
                -(mHeight * scale - mHeight) / 2);

        // move x and y distance
        mMatrix.postTranslate(-(x - (mWidth / 2)) * scale, 0);
        mMatrix.postTranslate(0, -(y - (mHeight / 2)) * scale);
        setImageMatrix(mMatrix);
    }

    public void cutting() {
        int width = (int) (mIntrinsicWidth * getScale());
        int height = (int) (mIntrinsicHeight * getScale());
        if (getTranslateX() < -(width - mWidth)) {
            mMatrix.postTranslate(-(getTranslateX() + width - mWidth), 0);
        }
        if (getTranslateX() > 0) {
            mMatrix.postTranslate(-getTranslateX(), 0);
        }
        if (getTranslateY() < -(height - mHeight)) {
            mMatrix.postTranslate(0, -(getTranslateY() + height - mHeight));
        }
        if (getTranslateY() > 0) {
            mMatrix.postTranslate(0, -getTranslateY());
        }
        if (width < mWidth) {
            mMatrix.postTranslate((mWidth - width) / 2, 0);
        }
        if (height < mHeight) {
            mMatrix.postTranslate(0, (mHeight - height) / 2);
        }
        setImageMatrix(mMatrix);
    }

    private float distance(float x0, float x1, float y0, float y1) {
        float x = x0 - x1;
        float y = y0 - y1;
        return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    private float dispDistance() {
        return FloatMath.sqrt(mWidth * mWidth + mHeight * mHeight);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (mDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
            return true;
        }
        int touchCount = event.getPointerCount();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_1_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN:
            if (touchCount >= 2) {
                float distance = distance(event.getX(0), event.getX(1),
                        event.getY(0), event.getY(1));
                mPrevDistance = distance;
                isScaling = true;
            } else {
                mPrevMoveX = (int) event.getX();
                mPrevMoveY = (int) event.getY();
            }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (touchCount >= 2 && isScaling) {
                float dist = distance(event.getX(0), event.getX(1),
                        event.getY(0), event.getY(1));
                float scale = (dist - mPrevDistance) / dispDistance();
                mPrevDistance = dist;
                scale += 1;
                scale = scale * scale;
                zoomTo(scale, mWidth / 2, mHeight / 2);
                cutting();
            } else if (!isScaling) {
                int distanceX = mPrevMoveX - (int) event.getX();
                int distanceY = mPrevMoveY - (int) event.getY();
                mPrevMoveX = (int) event.getX();
                mPrevMoveY = (int) event.getY();
                mMatrix.postTranslate(-distanceX, -distanceY);
                cutting();
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_UP:
            if (event.getPointerCount() <= 1) {
                isScaling = false;
            }
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

}
```

Comment: well, i was more likely asking if something could be changed inside img.setOnTouchListener, not write a whole new program, because i saw some answers close to mine, but i just can't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Try it that way:

```
img.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {          
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) img.getLayoutParams();

                        int x = (int) event.getRawX();
                        int y = (int) event.getRawY();

                        mParams.leftMargin = x;
                        mParams.topMargin = y;

                        img.setLayoutParams(mParams);                           
                    }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

You need to return true when the ACTION_DOWN event is triggered to indicate that you are interested in the subsequent calls relating to that same event.